How to find the transfer function of the Laplace expression
The function is $$Q_2(s)[C_2R_2s+\frac{R_2}{R_1}+1]=\frac{Q(s)}{R_1C_1s+1}+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{Q_2(s)}{R_1C_1s+1}$$
and the transfer function is $\frac{Q_2(s)}{Q(s)}$
The final form should be $$\frac{Q_2(s)}{Q(s)}=\frac{1}{C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2+(C_1R_1+C_2R_2+C_1R_2)s+1}$$
Subtracting the $Q_2(s)$ term from the right
$$Q_2(s)\left[C_2R_2s+\frac{R_2}{R_1}+1\right]-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{Q_2(s)}{R_1C_1s+1}=\frac{Q(s)}{R_1C_1s+1}$$
$$Q_2(s)\left[C_2R_2s+\frac{R_2}{R_1}+1-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1}{R_1C_1s+1}\right]=\frac{Q(s)}{R_1C_1s+1}$$
Multiplying by right side denominator and dividing by $Q_2(s)$
$$C_2R_2s(R_1C_1s+1 )+\frac{R_2}{R_1}(R_1C_1s+1 )+ (R_1C_1s+1)-\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1}{R_1C_1s+1}\right){R_1C_1s+1}=\frac{Q(s)}{Q_2(s)}$$
$$C_1C_1R_1R_2s^2+C_2R_2s+\frac{C_1R_1R_2s}{R_1}+\frac{R_2}{R_1}+R_1C_1s+1-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{R_1C_1s+1}{R_1C_1s+1}=\frac{Q(s)}{Q_2(s)}$$
I’ve taken it a few steps further than the last equation but I cannot see how to get it into the form given in my textbook.

I think something is incorrect or missing from either the starting equation or the ending equation.

$\frac{Q(s)}{Q_2(s)}=R_1C_1R_2C_2\cdot s^2+((R_1+R_2)C_1+R_2C_2)\cdot s+1$

Yeah I put an additional $C_1$ variable instead of a $C_2$ for the final form.
